# JSON is not working in Android 4.x (Phonegap)

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, json, cordova

I'm new in phonegap and javascript and I have a problem.
I have an url to download a JSON file which contains some pictures.
I tried these methods:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myurl.json',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Read json");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
$.get("myurl.json", function(data) {
    alert("alert");
}, "json");
$.get("myurl.json", function(data) {
    alert("alert");
});
$.getJSON("myurl.json", function(data) {
    alert("alert");
});
```

They are working in Android 2.x, but in Android 4.x the response is `null`.
In Android 4.x I have this error on LogCat :

`06-03 10:25:34.205: I/Choreographer(2795): Skipped 43 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

When it fails, the textStatus returns `parsererror`.

Could you help me? Thanks.